# Getting actual generic types of "super super" class or interface using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following interface/classes structure:

```
public interface IConverter<I, O> {    
    O convert(I value);
}
class ToViewConverter<I, O> implements IConverter<I, O>;
class NameToViewConverter<O> extends ToViewConverter<String, O>;
class RoleNameToViewConverter extends NameToViewConverter<Integer>;
```

I want ot get the ACTUAL types  and  (from IConverter) in runtime using refelection.
For the example of RoleNameToViewConverter, I want to get String and Integer respectively.
Is there any way to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this document very helpful:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/advanced-java-generics-retreiving-generic-type-arguments.html

It's not exactly what I wanted, as it doesn't handle interfaces, but only classes.
Anyway, it may be sufficient for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is some way to do this although it's not very nice:

```
RoleNameToViewConverter foo = new RoleNameToViewConverter();
System.out.println(foo.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
System.out.println(foo.getClass().getSuperclass().getGenericSuperclass());
```

This will print:

```
NameToViewConverter<java.lang.Integer>
ToViewConverter<java.lang.String, O>
```

Out of the first line you can get the `Integer` and out of the Second line you can get the `String`

Comment: That's fine, but I need something that will work generally for any class which one of it's super classes implements IConverter.

Comment: You'll have to implement that by yourself... (You can do that by recursively running through the superclasses and comparing the used generic values with the needed ones)